# How to update a 'second' GridView based on an update on 'first' GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updating

I'm creating an web form more complicated than what I'm listing below.

Bottom line, I'm updating a GridView and I'd like to have the 2nd Gridview update itself based on the GridView change made on the first one!

Please, help! I've already tried including a    `GridView2.DataBind()`    line in the     `updateNumber()`     method, but I receive an instance reference error or something like that. I've been stuck on this for days!

I update the number in `GridView1`, it refreshes and updates with new number, but NOT GridView2, which should display the updated number on `GridView1` (and yes, I do need `GridView2` to call     `GetUpdateNumber()`     `GridView2` still shows the old number... the ones prior to updating `GridView1`

Here is the code behind

```
    Option Strict On

Imports Team.MyWebProject

Public Class Blah
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim myNumberClass As New myClass1
        Dim mylist As New List(Of myClass1)

        Try
            If (Not IsPostBack) Then
                If Session("Number") Is Nothing Then
                    myNumberClass.number = 2
                    mylist.Add(myNumberClass)
                    Session("Number") = mylist
                Else
                    myNumberClass = Nothing
                    mylist = CType(Session("Number"), List(Of myClass1))
                End If
            Else
                mylist = CType(Session("Number"), List(Of myClass1))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "/Blah.aspx.vb Page_Load")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function getNumber() As List(Of myClass1)
        Try
            Dim mylist As List(Of myClass1) = CType(Session("Number"), List(Of myClass1))

            Return mylist
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "/Blah.aspx.vb GetNumber")
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function getUpdatedNumber() As List(Of myClass1)
        Try
            Dim mylist As List(Of myClass1) = CType(Session("Number"), List(Of myClass1))

            Return mylist
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "/Blah.aspx.vb GetUpdateNumber")
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub updateNumber(ByVal number As Integer)
        Try
            Dim mylist As List(Of myClass1) = CType(Session(Number"), List(Of myClass1))
            Dim LoopIndex As New Integer
            LoopIndex = 0

            For Each Match In mylist
                mylist(LoopIndex).Number = number
                LoopIndex += 1
            Next

            Session("Number") = mylist

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "blah.aspx.vb updateNumber")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "Blah.aspx.vb GridView13_RowUpdating()")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView2_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView2.DataBinding
        Try
            Dim mylist As List(Of myClass1) = CType(Session("Number"), List(Of myClass1))

            getUpdatedNumber()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "Blah.aspx GridView2_Databinding()")

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Here is the myClass1.vb class:

    Namespace MyWebProject

    Public Class myClass1
        Private _number As Integer

        Public Sub New()
            _number = 0
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal number As Integer)
            _number = number
        End Sub

        Public Property Number() As Integer
            Get
                Return _number
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _number = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Namespace

And here is the MarkUp page: 

    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Blah.aspx.vb" Inherits="GridViewUpdateTest.Blah" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="getNumber" TypeName="GridViewUpdateTest.Blah" UpdateMethod="updateNumber">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="number" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="getUpdatedNumber" TypeName="GridViewUpdateTest.Blah"></asp:ObjectDataSource>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the event on which you want to update the second gridview?

Comment: The 2nd Gridview (GridView2) should update automatically, after the EDIT is done on the first Gridview (GridView1)  So, the GridView1 is edited, updated, and it 'refreshes' and updates, but when this occurs, GridView2 doesn't update nor 'refreshes'... how can I get GridView2 to do this right after GridView1 is updated? GV2 should update itself and reflect the changes done on GV1... basically, they both should end up showing the same scores!